# PHP/mysql count duplicates and output as numbers

Tags: php, mysql, count

I want to count all duplicates and output them as a number.

database:

```
user   
Sam
Sam    
Tom    
Tom    
Tom 
John
```

and here is my code:

```
 $sql = "select user, count(*) duplicates from users group by user order by duplicates desc";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
  
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          // output data of each row
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo $row["user"]. "<br>";
          }
      } else {
          
      }
```

well this works but here is the output:

```
Tom
Sam
John
```

i want the output to be only numbers:

```
3
2
1
```

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Just: `select count(*) duplicates from users group by user order by duplicates desc`?

Comment: @AlandSleman sure it does https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b6dLPM7GnCCSaJqya5aKS6/0

Comment: @GMB the sql statement works but when you put it into my code it doesn't work

Comment: Suggest never using the phase 'doesn't work' when asking for help. It can mean so many things. Act as a professional and give people who volunteer their time here a meaningful response. Why not? Did it error? Did the result not meet your ever changing specification?

Comment: @danblack it returns else,blank. nothing happens

Comment: Add `$row["duplicates"]` to your other echo'd row, seeing you're using `duplicates` as an alias.

Comment: If that doesn't work ^, then your table's columns might not be properly set with the right data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SQL` to count (as you did) and store the number in a attribute. This attribute can be read directly in PHP. You have to declare your count variable with `AS` in SQL.

```
$sql = "select user, count(*) AS duplicates from users group by user order by duplicates desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
    echo $row["duplicates"]. "<br>";
  }
} 
else 
{
}
```

Comment: @AlandSleman The SQL statement should work. Your counts getting stored in duplicates. I tested it in DB Fiddle you provided. The DB connection work, you tested that? Have you fetched some data already with basic select * from users?

Comment: Thank you it worked there was something else wrong.

Comment: @AlandSleman can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting the `user` column, select the `ID` column:

```
$sql = "select ID, count(*) duplicates from users group by user order by duplicates desc";
```

And then output the ID column in your `echo`:

```
echo $row["ID"]. "<br>";
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i want users only.Question edited

Comment: That will get you what you the output that you asked for; a count of the users who are duplicates. Your update to the question still seems to incidate that this is what you want; not really sure why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: I tried yours too, It doesn't works returns else, Nothing happens.

Comment: @ObsidianAge There is no attribute called Id. The numbers he is using above are the sum of the specific name.

Comment: @AlandSleman However, It looks like your PHP code might be wrong. Please share the whole database connection code, so we can investigate. The SQL queries are correct